# using igraph to plot asymmetric ties

Tags: r, igraph, data-manipulation, adjacency-matrix, sna

`HAVE` is a two-mode adjacency matrix of **lead actors** (ids in the 1st column) and **supporting actors** (ids in the column names).

```
    f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7
f1  0   1   0   2   5   0   6
f2  0   0   3   0   0   6   0
f3  9   4   0   1   0   0   0
```

The numbers in the matrix are film counts. The matrix is asymmetric. For example, f2 played the lead in a film with f3 in a supporting role *three* times, but f3 was the lead in a film where f2 supported *four* times.

I need to produce a directed graph where arrows are drawn from actors to supporters - the size of the arrow/arc needs to be proportional to the number of `films`. See below for the mock-up of the f2-f3 dyad:[image]

The identical naming conventions in both "modes" of the graph obviously cause problems. Let me know if you have any clear solutions, or if I'm not asking my question well (I'm new to igraph and two-mode projections). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the help page `help(igraph.plotting)`, you can find that it says:

> arrow.size
>
> The size of the arrows. Currently this is a constant, so it
>   is the same for every edge.

So I do not think it is possible to accomplish this by the size of the arrow head. However, it certainly is possible to vary the line width of the arrows using the parameter `edge.width`.

Since you do not provide any data, I am including a small example that I think you should be able to match to your problem.

**Sample Data**

```
CoStar = matrix(c(0,1,3,1, 3,0,3,1, 2,1,0,0, 0,1,1,0), nrow=4)
CoStar
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    3    2    0
[2,]    1    0    1    1
[3,]    3    3    0    1
[4,]    1    1    0    0
```

Now we can turn this into a graph object and display it using the weights as the edge width. You need to use the `edge.curved` parameter so that the edge A->B is not on top of the edge B->A.

```
library(igraph)
G = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(CoStar, weighted=TRUE)
V(G)$label = c("Steve", "Sean", "Andy", "Tim")
plot(G, edge.width=E(G)$weight+1, edge.arrow.size=1.5, edge.curved=0.25)
```

[image: Asymmetric graph]

You can see that the edge sizes are proportional to the weights (number of joint appearances).

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much - sorry I didn't include my data. I've added it for reference in case other users find it useful.